# Are there any good references to modular form and its application to quadratic forms

Tags: reference-request, modular-forms, quadratic-forms

I am a beginner of this interesting branch of mathematics，I have read N.Koblitz's Introduction to Ellipitic Curves and Modular Forms.I am familiar with the arithmetic theory of quadratic forms.Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may begin with Serre, a Course in Arithmetics. The last chapter is an introduction to modular forms with a last section on Theta series and their applications to quadratic forms.

Comment: Another more detailed source is Henryk Iwaniec's book "Topics in Classical Automorphic Forms". Chapters 10 and 11 are devoted to theta functions and representations by quadratic forms.

Comment: More appropriate for MSE?